# Cortex- A8(OMAP3515) : Data abort while accessing external ram when D-cache is enabled

Tags: caching, arm, ram, mmu, omap

I am using Omap3515 (Arm Cortex A8). Enabled I-Cache, D-Cache, Branch Prediction and MMU.

And also I am getting a data abort, if I try to copy a frame buffer of 600KB from an external memory region to another external memory region.
(If I copy 100KB are less then there is no abort. Even some times for copying 400KB also there is no data abort.)
After the data abort, I could notice that the SDR i.e SDRAM is not accessible.

I have enabled MMU in such a way that PA=VA.

If I disable D-Cache then there is no abort and it works fine. But I would like to enable D-Cache for faster access.

Here is the code

```
            .arm
            .sect     EntryOnReset


;//         Module Imports and exports          
            .global   ResetHandler
            .global   RelocateImage
            .global   OasysEntry
            .global   BoardInit
            .global    __stack
            .global   __STACK_SIZE
  .global   NEONCopyPLD
  .global   EnableCaches
  .global   DisableCaches
  .global   MemmoryTest
            .global   core_init

;// Stack Size Definition.
UND_Stack_Size  .EQU     0x00000100
SVC_Stack_Size  .EQU     0x00001000      ;//Only main function stack is to be mentioned here.
ABT_Stack_Size  .EQU     0x00000100
FIQ_Stack_Size  .EQU     0x00000100
IRQ_Stack_Size  .EQU     0x00000100
USR_Stack_Size  .EQU     0x00000100
;//******************************************************************************
;//                                EQUATES
;//******************************************************************************
;// Standard definitions of Mode bits and Interrupt (I & F) flags in PSRs
Mode_USR        .EQU     0x10
Mode_FIQ        .EQU     0x11
Mode_IRQ        .EQU     0x12
Mode_SVC        .EQU     0x13
Mode_ABT        .EQU     0x17
Mode_UND        .EQU     0x1B
Mode_SYS        .EQU     0x1F
I_Bit           .EQU     0x80            ;// when I bit is set, IRQ is disabled
F_Bit           .EQU     0x40            ;// when F bit is set, FIQ is disabled
;//******************************************************************************
;//                                EQUATES
;//******************************************************************************
FIQ_IRQ_DISABLE .EQU  0xC0               ;//Disable both FIQ and IRQ.


;//******************************************************************************
;//                             CODE GENERATION DIRECTIVES
;//******************************************************************************
;// Area Definition and Entry Point
;// Startup Code must be linked first at Address at which it expects to run.
;//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;//******************************************************************************
;// Routine name    : ENTRY
;// Description     : Entry point for software.
;// Assumptions     : <none>
;// Tainted registers  :  <none>
;//  Functions called  :
;// Low level
;// Requirements       :
;//
;//    1. This routine shall initialize the Stack pointer.
;//
;//    2. This routine shall perform architecture specific
;//       initializations by calling InitCPU routine.
;//******************************************************************************
ResetHandler:


;==================================================================
; Enable access to NEON/VFP by enabling access to Coprocessors 10 and 11.
; Enables Full Access i.e. in both privileged and non privileged modes
;==================================================================
        MRC     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #2      ; Read Coprocessor Access Control Register (CPACR)
        ORR     r0, r0, #(0xF << 20)       ; Enable access to CP 10 & 11
        MCR     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #2      ; Write Coprocessor Access Control Register (CPACR)
        ISB
;==================================================================
; Switch on the VFP and NEON hardware
;=================================================================
        MOV     r0, #0x40000000
        VMSR    FPEXC, r0                   ; Write FPEXC register, EN bit set






    ;@ Disable MMU.
    MRC p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #0                               ;@ Read Control Register configuration data.
    BIC r1, r1, #0x1
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #0                               ;@ Write Control Register configuration data.

    ;@ Disable L1 Caches.
    MRC p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #0                               ;@ Read Control Register configuration data.
    BIC r1, r1, #(0x1 << 12)                                ;@ Disable I Cache.
    BIC r1, r1, #(0x1 << 2)                                 ;@ Disable D Cache.
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #0                               ;@ Write Control Register configuration data

    ;@ Invalidate L1 Caches.
    ;@ Invalidate Instruction cache.
    MOV r1, #0
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c7, c5, #0


    ;@ Invalidate Data cache.
    ;@ To make the code general purpose, calculate the
    ;@ cache size first and loop through each set + way.


    MRC p15, #1, r0, c0, c0, #0                               ;@ Read Cache Size ID.
;TBR LDR r3, #0x1FF
    MOV r3, #0x1FF
    AND r0, r3, r0, LSR #13                                 ;@ r0 = no. of sets - 1.


    MOV r1, #0                              ;@ r1 = way counter way_loop.
way_loop:
    MOV r3, #0                              ;@ r3 = set counter set_loop.
set_loop:
    MOV r2, r1, LSL #30
;TBR ORR r2, r3, LSL #5                              ;@ r2 = set/way cache operation format.
    ORR r2, r2, r3, LSL #5                              ;@ r2 = set/way cache operation format.
    MCR p15, #0, r2, c7, c6, #2                               ;@ Invalidate the line described by r2.
    ADD r3, r3, #1                              ;@ Increment set counter.
    CMP r0, r3                              ;@ Last set reached yet?
    BGT set_loop                                ;@ If not, iterate set_loop,
    ADD r1, r1, #1                              ;@ else, next.
    CMP r1, #4                              ;@ Last way reached yet?
    BNE way_loop                                ;@ if not, iterate way_loop.


    ;@ Invalidate TLB
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c8, c7, #0


    ;@ Branch Prediction Enable.
    MOV r1, #0
    MRC p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #0                               ;@ Read Control Register configuration data.
    ORR r1, r1, #(0x1 << 11)                                ;@ Global BP Enable bit.
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #0                               ;@ Write Control Register configuration data.


    ;@ Enable D-side Prefetch
    MRC p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #1                               ;@ Read Auxiliary Control Register.
    ORR r1, r1, #(0x1 <<2)                              ;@ Enable D-side prefetch.
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #1;                              ;@ Write Auxiliary Control Register.
    DSB
    ISB
    ;@ DSB causes completion of all cache maintenance operations appearing in program
    ;@ order before the DSB instruction.
    ;@ An ISB instruction causes the effect of all branch predictor maintenance
    ;@ operations before the ISB instruction to be visible to all instructions
    ;@ after the ISB instruction.
    ;@ Initialize PageTable.


    ;@ It would be faster to create this in a read-only section in an assembly file.


                                                    ;@ descriptor.
    LDR r1, tlb_l1_base
    MOV r2, #0
    MOV r4, #1
write_pte
    MOV r0, #0x0E
    ORR r0, r0, r4, LSL #0xA
    ORR r0, r0, r4, LSL #0xB
    ORR r0, r0, r2, LSL #20
    STR r0, [r1]
    ADD r1, r1, #4
    ADD r2, r2, #1                                 ;@ Decrement loop counter.
    SUBS r3, r2, #4096
    BNE write_pte


    ;@ Initialize MMU.
    MOV r1,#0x0
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c2, c0, #2                               ;@ Write Translation Table Base Control Register.
    LDR r1, tlb_l1_base
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c2, c0, #0                               ;@ Write Translation Table Base Register 0.


    ;@ In this simple example, do not use TRE or Normal Memory Remap Register.
    ;@ Set all Domains to Manger.
    MOV r1, #0xFFFF             ; Provied Manager access, so access premition bits (AP) shall not be checked.
    ORR r1, r1, r1, LSL #0x10
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c3, c0, #0                                   ;@ Write Domain Access Control Register.


    ;@ Enable MMU
    MRC p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #0                                   ;@ Read Control Register configuration data.
    ORR r1, r1, #0x1                                    ;@ Bit 0 is the MMU enable.
    MCR p15, #0, r1, c1, c0, #0                                   ;@ Write Control Register configuration data.


tlb_l1_base .word 0x40200000


;//******************************************************************************
;//                              SETUP STACK POINTERS FOR USR MODE
;//******************************************************************************
;*------------------------------------------------------
;* INITIALIZE THE USER MODE STACK
;*------------------------------------------------------
StackInit:
  LDR     sp, c_stack
  LDR     r0, c_STACK_SIZE
  ADD     sp, sp, r0
;*-----------------------------------------------------
;* Clear upper 3 bits for 64-bit alignment.
;*-----------------------------------------------------
  BIC     sp, sp, #0x07


  ;// Set IRQ and FIQ bits in CPSR to disable all interrupts.
  MRS     R0, CPSR
  STMFD   SP!, {R0}                   ;// Store it onto stack
  ORR     R1, R0, #FIQ_IRQ_DISABLE
  MSR     CPSR_c, R1


;//******************************************************************************
;//                              SETUP STACK FOR OTHER MODES
;//******************************************************************************
  MOV     R0, SP
;//  Enter Undefined Instruction Mode and set its Stack Pointer
        MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_UND|I_Bit|F_Bit
        MOV     SP, R0
        SUB     R0, R0, #UND_Stack_Size


;//  Enter Abort Mode and set its Stack Pointer
        MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_ABT|I_Bit|F_Bit
        MOV     SP, R0
        SUB     R0, R0, #ABT_Stack_Size


;//  Enter FIQ Mode and set its Stack Pointer
        MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_FIQ|I_Bit|F_Bit
        MOV     SP, R0
        SUB     R0, R0, #FIQ_Stack_Size


;//  Enter IRQ Mode and set its Stack Pointer
        MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_IRQ|I_Bit|F_Bit
        MOV     SP, R0
        SUB     R0, R0, #IRQ_Stack_Size


;//  Enter Supervisor Mode and set its Stack Pointer
        MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_SVC|I_Bit|F_Bit
        MOV     SP, R0
        SUB     R0, R0, #SVC_Stack_Size


        MSR     CPSR_c, #Mode_SVC|I_Bit


;//******************************************************************************
;//                                   MOVE TO myfunc
;//******************************************************************************
;//  The following routine copies the loaded image to execution region.
                BL      RelocateImage
;//  The following routine initialises the Omap3515.
     BL BoardInit
;//  The following routine enaables the MMU.
                ;BL      EnableMMU
;//  The following routine enables the I cache.
                BL      EnableICaches
;//  The following routine enables branch prediction.
                BL      EnableBrachPrediction
;//  The following routine enables the D cache.
                BL      EnableDCaches
;//  The following routine enables the L2 cache.
                ;BL      EnableL2UnifiedCache
;//  The following routine starts the OS.
                BL      MemmoryTest


;===================================================================
; Enable MMU and Branch to __main
; Leaving the caches disabled until after scatter loading.
;===================================================================
    .global EnableMMU
;******************************************************************************
;               c1, Control Register
;       [0] M bit Banked                  Enables the MMU:
;                                         0 = MMU disabled, reset value
;                                         1 = MMU enabled.
;******************************************************************************
EnableMMU:
    ;Read the c1 register
    mrc p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #0
    ;Set b1 - Enables the MMU
    orr r0, r0, #0x1
    ; Write back to c1 register to enable MMU
    mcr p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #0
    BX      lr


    .global EnableICaches
;==================================================================
;  This API enables instruction cache.
;==================================================================
EnableICaches:
        MRC     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #0      ; Read System Control Register
        ORR     r0, r0, #(0x1 << 12)         ; Set I bit 12 to enable I Cache
        ;BIC   r0, r0, #(0x1  <<12)         ; Clear bit 0
        MCR     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #0      ; Write System Control Register
        BX      lr


    .global EnableDCaches
;==================================================================
;  This API enables data cache.
;==================================================================
EnableDCaches:
        MRC     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #0      ; Read System Control Register
       ORR     r0, r0, #(0x1 << 2)          ; Set C bit  2 to enable D Cache
       ;BIC   r0, r0, #(0x1  << 2)           ; Clear bit 0              
       ;BIC     r0, r0, #(0x1 << 1)          ; disable alignment checks
        MCR     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #0      ; Write System Control Register
        BX      lr


    .global EnableL2UnifiedCache
;==================================================================
; Enable Cortex-A8 Level2 Unified Cache
;==================================================================
EnableL2UnifiedCache:
        MRC     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #1      ; Read Auxiliary Control Register
        ORR     r0, r0, #2                     ; L2EN bit, enable L2 cache
        ;BIC   r0, r0, #(0x1  << 1)         ; L2EN bit, disable L2 cache
        ;ORR     r0, r0, #(0x1  << 4)        ;Enables speculative accesses on AXI
        ORR     r0, r0, #(0x1  << 4)        ;Enables speculative accesses on AXI
        ORR     r0, r0, #(0x1  << 5)        ;Enables caching NEON data within the L1 data cache
        MCR     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #1      ; Write Auxiliary Control Register
        BX      lr


    .global EnableBrachPrediction
;==================================================================
;  This API enables branch prediction
;==================================================================
EnableBrachPrediction:
        MRC     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #0      ; Read System Control Register
        ORR     r0, r0, #(0x1 << 11)        ; Set Z bit 11 to enable branch prediction
        ;BIC    r0, r0, #(0x1  << 11)       ; Disable all forms of branch prediction
        MCR     p15, #0, r0, c1, c0, #0      ; Write System Control Register
        BX      lr

c_stack:        .long   __stack
c_STACK_SIZE:   .long   __STACK_SIZE
;//******************************************************************************
;//                                POINTERS TO VARIABLES
;//******************************************************************************
;    ENDIF


    .END
```

Thanks and regards,
Krish

Answer (score 0):

The Cortex-A caches generally write allocate, so the write succeeds, and only faults "late" when the cache line is evicted. I would guess your pagetable is set up incorrectly.

If you look at the DFAR ans DFSR (data fault status register, and data fault address register), you should get more specific information about the fault and the triggering address.